# If else for multiple critera for listbox in a form is failing

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a form for data entry. I have a listbox in the form and the data is populated based on so selected criteria in a combobox and another criteria in another combo box. The problem is that the first criteria which relies on the values from a combobox and another preselected listbox does not execute. I can seem to figure out that I am missing. I have also used select case but the codes didn't execute for this same expression line. I don't get any error message. The code just doesn't execute. Maybe some one can take a look? Thank you so much!!!
Below is my code:

```
Private Sub subout_Change()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Worksheets("DataFeed")
  Dim suboutp, suboutpext, subazt As Range
  Dim prov4, prov5, prov6 As Variant
   Dim lCountList As Long


   prov4 = subout.Value


    Me.suboutp.Clear

   With Me.outpro
      For lCountList = 0 To .ListCount - 1
          If .Selected(lCountList) = True Then
               prov5 = .List(lCountList)
          End If
       Next lCountList
    End With

If (prov5 = Left("abc", 3)) And (prov4 = "YES-external") Then
    For Each subazt In Range("SubOutAZT")
            With Me.suboutp
                .AddItem subazt.Value
            End With
        Next subazt

ElseIf (prov4 = "YES-internal") Then
    For Each suboutp In Range("IntSubOut")
        With Me.suboutp
        .AddItem suboutp.Value
        End With
    Next suboutp

 ElseIf (prov4 = "YES-external") Then

        For Each suboutpext In Range("ExtSubOut")
                With Me.suboutp
                    .AddItem suboutpext.Value
                End With
         Next suboutpext

ElseIf prov4 = "NO" Then
             With Me.suboutp
                    .Clear
             End With

        Else
             With Me.suboutp
                    .Clear
             End With
            End If
 End Sub
```

This line doesn't execute

```
 ** If (prov5 = Left("abc", 3)) And (prov4 = "YES-external") Then
    For Each subazt In Range("SubOutAZT")
            With Me.suboutp
                .AddItem subazt.Value
            End With
        Next subazt**
```

I cant figure out why. **outpro** is a listbox, and **subout** is a combobox while **suboutp** is a listbox. **suboutp** depends on the value selected from the first two.

Thank you so much

Comment: shouldnt the validation have 2 equalto signs? ==

Comment: `prov5 = Left("abc", 3)` doesn't make much sense did you eventually mean `Left(prov5 , 3) = "abc"`?

Comment: @LuckyChingi there's no `==` operator in VBA

Comment: @peh I want once an input that starts with 'abc' is selected in the listbox, and external is selected in the other box, then the code has to execute. I used this in select case before but after I changed to ifelse, it stopped executing. I guess with ifelse, I have to put it the other way round, or?

Comment: I just looked at your code and saw that `prov5 = Left("abc", 3)` is exactly the same like `prov5 = "abc"` because the `Left("abc", 3)` means take the left 3 characters of `"abc"` and this is always `abc`. So I guess you wanted to know if `prov5` starts with `abc` therefore you would need to get the left 3 characters from `prov5` and check if they match `abc` like `Left(prov5 , 3) = "abc"` So this is a general issue and has nothing to do with wether you use `If` or `Select`.

Comment: @peh  Thank you so much!! It was the correction i needed. i can't believe i didn't even see that. My brain was totally deceiving me. I made the correction and it worked like a charm! Updated code below:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much @Peh for your extra pair of eyes. This is the updated code for people who may need it. It works in my userform which powers changes for one of my dependent selections for listbox and combobox. Modify as needed!

```
Private Sub subout_Change()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("DataFeed")
    Dim suboutp, suboutpext, subazt As Range
    Dim prov4, prov5 As Variant
    Dim lCountList As Long


      prov4 = subout.Value 'this is a combobox that contains several dropdown values.


       Me.suboutp.Clear 'this is the listbox i am trying to populate with which change in selection from combobox above and listbox below

       With Me.outpro ' this is another list box that has a specific dependency for the second listbox above
  For lCountList = 0 To .ListCount - 1
      If .Selected(lCountList) = True Then
           prov5 = .List(lCountList)
      End If
   Next lCountList
End With

 If  Left(prov5, 3)="abc" And (prov4 = "YES-external") Then
      For Each subazt In Range("SubOutAZT")
        With Me.suboutp
            .AddItem subazt.Value
        End With
    Next subazt

ElseIf (prov4 = "YES-internal") Then
  For Each suboutp In Range("IntSubOut")
    With Me.suboutp
    .AddItem suboutp.Value
    End With
Next suboutp

  ElseIf (prov4 = "YES-external") Then

    For Each suboutpext In Range("ExtSubOut")
            With Me.suboutp
                .AddItem suboutpext.Value
            End With
     Next suboutpext

ElseIf prov4 = "NO" Then
         With Me.suboutp
                .Clear
         End With

      Else
         With Me.suboutp
                .Clear
         End With
        End If
End Sub
```